# 2015 Kia Sedona brake light problem

Tags: brakes, lights, kia, tail-lights, sedona

Our 2015 Kia Sedona has recently developed a problem with the brake lights. Only the top LED brake light turns on when the petal is depressed. Here is a list of details:

- Only the top, rear, center brake light works, which leads us to believe that the switch is not the root of our problem.
- When we tried to start the vehicle without the brake light fuse, it did not let us start it. Therefore, keeping in mind it did not do this normally, the fuse is not the problem.
- We can turn on all rear lights, meaning the socket or bulb is not the problem.

Here is some things that we think may cause the problem, but aren't sure:

- We may have accidentally changed some kind of setting in the vehicle.
- The wiring may be damaged.

Answer (score 1):

Check the brake light bulbs - they have two filaments, one for marker or side lights and the other for brake lights.

The marker light filament is 5W and the brake is 21W.